# Replacing HTML code with character entity

Tags: java

I have String which contains HTML code like `&#148;` & `&#146;` etc. I want to replace it with respective entity set like (`"` & `'`) in Java. I have tried following code.

---

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)) {
    string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(string);
    string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(string);
    string = string.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
    string = string.trim();
}
```

---

Input String :

```
brief is a tie side, string style embellished with shimmering silver sequins. 
Dangling gunmetal chain tassels decorate the end of each hip tie. Model&amp;apos;s 
Measurements   Height 5&amp;apos;10.5&amp;quot; Hips 36&amp;#148; Waist 23.5&amp;#148; 
Model wears size 2
```

I am getting following output which contains BadEncoding:

```
brief is a tie side, string style embellished with shimmering silver 
sequins. Dangling gunmetal chain tassels decorate the end of each hip tie. Model's 
Measurements   Height 5'10.5" Hips 36<94> Waist 23.5<94> Bust 35<94> Model wears size 2
```

Required Output:

```
brief is a tie side, string style embellished with shimmering silver sequins. 
Dangling gunmetal chain tassels decorate the end of each hip tie. Model's 
Measurements   Height 5'10.5" Hips 36" Waist 23.5" Bust 35" Model wears size 2
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: The input starts with `breif`, the output with `The Zonia bikini`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Are you calling `unescapeHtml3` or `unescapeHtml4`?

Comment: I have made chaanges ion output line.@Behrang

Comment: not sure about unescapeHtml3 or unescapeHtml4. how can i check this? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: If you paste code in your question and you use an external library then be sure to tell us what it is!  (yes, in this case I know what it is, but not telling this as part of the question is just not nice!)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just numeric character escapes, the number is a character number and can be used fairly directly by just converting it to an int and thence to a char. See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes